# How likely is it for a quantum random walker to fall off a cliff?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Consider a setup like this:

[image: quantum random walk]

We're given a 2-state unitary operation $U$, and a system in the state $|0\rangle$. We then repeat the following process indefinitely:

- Apply $U$ to every adjacent integer pair that starts with an even number.
- Apply $U$ to the other adjacent integer pairs, the ones that start with an odd number.
- Measure whether the walker's position is negative or non-negative.
- If the position is negative, the walker fell off the cliff and we stop.
- Repeat.

For example, if $U$ is the Hadamard operation, then the state progression goes like so:

1. $|0\rangle$
2. $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}|0\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}|1\rangle$
3. $\frac{1}{2}|\text{fell}\rangle - \frac{1}{2}|0\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|2\rangle$
4. 25% fell, else $\frac{2}{\sqrt 6}|0\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}|2\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}|3\rangle$
5. 25% fell, else $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}|\text{fell}\rangle - \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}|0\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}|1\rangle - \frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}|2\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}|3\rangle+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}|4\rangle$
6. 50% fell, else $-\frac{1}{\sqrt 8}|0\rangle + \frac{3}{\sqrt 8}|1\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|3\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}|4\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}|5\rangle$

And so forth, although it's a lot easier to keep track of things without the renormalizing after each step.

The question is: given $U$, what is the long-term probability of falling?

For example, if $U=X$ then the answer is 0%. And if $U=H$ then the answer is more than 50%, just from the steps I've shown above. How does the probability vary as we vary $U$?

Comment: The problem looks interesting but I think your question contravenes the homework and EXERCISES policy, which requires that you **show effort to solve the problem** and **ask about a specific physics concept**.

Comment: @sammygerbil I don't want to bog down the question talking about the stuff I tried that didn't work. The main obstacle, compared to the classical case, is that you can't add up amplitudes across time (e.g. by waiting for all of it to drain out of a finite subsection then tallying up the total). So even if you do a timelike slice, you need to track an array of values, and the array updates in ways that are hard to summarize. I keep ending up with sums containing a polynomial factor that increases every time I step a slice forward.

Comment: -1. For lack of research effort. After googling your title I got [Quantum random walk on the line as a markovian process](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0310171) as hit #3 - your question is #1 and #2. Note in particular the penultimate paragraph : *The Markovian approach presented here provides a systematic way to find the classical analog associated to a given quantum random walk. By reformulating the quantum problem as described here and neglecting the interference terms, the Markovian equation describing the equivalent classical problem can be readily obtained.*

Comment: @sammygerbil don't have to follow the policies dogmatically. if it looks interesting, +1 from me :)

Comment: @sammygerbil +1 from me too. apart from being an interesting question i also don't see at all how a Markov approximation would apply for the Hadamard operator.

Comment: @Mrphlng I did not say the question is not interesting. But that does is not one of voting criteria. Perhaps you mean *useful*? If you wish to answer the question, nobody is preventing you.

Comment: @innisfree There is no point having policies if they are not implemented consistently and fairly.

Comment: @sammygerbil i was really talking about the *content* of the question, and I disagree that the link you found has anything to do with the question. maybe *you* should put in some more research effort instead of googling the title and taking the first best link to criticise the question.

Comment: The classical question was asked on Puzzling.SE some time ago:  http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/6415/

Comment: @Mrphlng : In what way is the arXiv paper "nothing to do with the question"? How many different problems are there with the name *quantum random walk on a line*? The OP is asking for a solution method, that paper provides one which avoids the quadratic (polynomial?) increase in variance which the OP found. If you know the subject better than those authors, and that their approach will not work, why don't you write to enlighten them? It was only the first google hit after the OP's question, but there were many others. The point is that much has been published on this problem already.

Comment: @sammygerbil Users shouldn't have to review the literature before asking a question. Stackexchange is built around *providing searchable answers*. Its strength is reducing the time it takes to get answers to dumb obvious questions, and your policies should cut along that line instead of against it.

Comment: @sammygerbil The paper you linked describes a different kind of random walk, where a qubit representing the direction to walk is being rotated between each step. The solutions may be related, but to me it doesn't seem like the relationship would be trivial.

Comment: Rotation about a fixed axis is analogous to motion along a straight line : both are 1D motions. In classical physics the equations of rotational kinematics correspond with those of linear kinematics. The paper calls the problem by the same name - quantum random walk *on the line* - despite applying it to a kicked rotator, which shows that they understand the 2 situations to be analogous.

Comment: @sammygerbil What I mean is that they are rotating the *velocity* (for lack of a better term), which then operates on the position, whereas I'm directly operating on the positions. And the resulting answers could be qualitatively different.

Comment: On the contrary, basic research is expected (see voting button), the minimum being a google search using your title. The google search engine is superior to the Physics SE engine. An internet search is definitely *not* a literature review, as any PhD examiner will tell you. ... I do not understand what difference a random walk in *angular velocity* makes. This is still a 1D problem. ... You seem determined to look for reasons to reject Romanelli's method instead of looking for a way of applying it. ... There were several other papers arising from the search. You could look at those instead.

Comment: @sammygerbil and there we go... as you say it requires to "look for a way of applying it". Would you mind writing an answer telling us how to? I'd be interested too.